# meaning of PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO on Mac with Intel CPU and AMD GPU

Tags: macos

I understand that on a M1 chip, the CPU and GPU share a memory pool and this PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO controls how much memory out of the shared pool the GPU can use. However on a Mac with Intel CPU with another AMD GPU, is there still a shared memory pool between the intel CPU and the AMD GPU? If not, does PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO still have any effect in this case?